# How to set background dynamically for an imageView from SD card?

Tags: android

I have the path of the image that is present in my SD card .i want to set this as the background for an imageview. Is that possible to use the same method as from URl?
Please help..

Comment: Look at comment at below my answer.. Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set background of image view first you have to create Drawable from image path and use `setBackgroundDrawable()` method to set background

**Try with the following code**

```
Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePathFromSDCard);
        Drawable drawableImage = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapImage);

        imageview.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableImage);
```

Comment: @user370305 You have edited your answer now. But previously you gave only one answer.

Comment: then you should accept your mistakes and should have accepted right comments rather than arguing on them